# When is the parentheses absolutely necessary in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to make sense of methods definitions with no arguments and parentheses. In the main method, last one does not work. What is the explanation for that semantically or syntactically?

```
class X(x:Int){
  def getX1() = x;
  def getX2 = x;
}

object X {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = new X(123)
    println(x.getX1)//works
    println(x.getX1())//works
    println(x.getX2) //works
    println(x.getX2())//does not work
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. If you have a method defined with () you can choose to call it with or without (). On the other hand, if you have a method defined without (), you can only call it without (). To me, it's a good practice to use () to signify side-effects.